# Output the number of cores and speed of a server?

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit

I have access to another college's standalone server and am running several experiments on it. However, I don't know how many cores or the speed of the cores in the machine. Is there a way to get that information through the command line? Right now I'm accessing it through SSH.

Comment: What operating system? SSH isn't a clue, as it's cross-platform.

Answer (score 8):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: That's assuming it's a *nix system.

Comment: ...that uses the `/proc` filesystem.